# Two non-stationary particles collide at different angles

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision, ideal-gas

So, I'm trying to write a simulation of an ideal gas in a container. I know that the collisions in this situation consist of elastic collisions with the walls and with other particles. I have implemented the former, however the latter is giving me some trouble. I have quickly come up with a crude diagram of the interaction as I understand it [image]

We see that, particle $M$ comes in with some angle $\phi_1$ and velocity $V_{1i}$ and collides with a particle of mass  $m$, angle $\theta_1$ and velocity $V_{2i}$. These are known quantities. It seems to me that I am able to create 2 equations from this system (from the conservation of horizontal and vertical momentum), however I have essentially 4 unknowns that make up the invariant quantity of kinetic energy, and since there are many ways I can combine them to ensure conservation, I cannot seem to achieve a result. How do you resolve this case?

My next idea was to use Lagrangian mechanics to form some equation of motion using the combined electrostatic potential of a molecules constituent electrons and protons but I haven't thought about it enough. Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this with a set of random velocity (vector) particles? I have an answer for that situation.

Comment: Yes I am indeed!

Comment: Due to conservation of momentum, and conservation of momentum for each vector component, shouldn't the angle of incidence equal the angle of reflection?

Comment: Well that's exactly what I thought but I couldn't prove that it was the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have a collection of particles with masses $m_j$ and velocities $\vec{v}_j$. Randomly select a pair of particles, let them "collide" elastically with a random impact parameter. As you do this, the energy, speed distributions of each different mass value, and velocity component distributions of each mass value will approach the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. I've done this starting with equal energies for one, two, and three different masses, as well as equal speeds for masses.

The trick to the random elastic collision is to transform to the center-of-mass reference frame.
$$\vec{v}_{jC}=\vec{v}_{j}-\vec{v}_{C}$$
where $\vec{v}_{C}$ is the velocity of the center of mass relative to the same frame in which the particle velocities have been determined.
$$\vec{v}_{C}=\frac{m_1\vec{v}_{1}+m_2\vec{v}_{2}}{m_1+m_2}$$
where the $1$ and $2$ subscripts represent the two randomly chosen particles.

With an elastic collision the velocity of the center of mass will not change, and the momentum in the center of mass is zero. All you have to do is randomly rotate the velocities of each particle by the same random angle $\phi$, once around one axis (e.g., "z") by using a matrix rotation operator like
$$ R_z=\pmatrix
{\cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
 \sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1}$$.

Then randomly rotate the new velocities at a different angle around a different axis, e.g. "x". Finally transform the two new velocities back to the original reference frame.

Choose two new particles and repeat.

The reason this works is that the impact parameters in the original frame are random, so the scattering interaction will be randomly distributed. In the center of mass frame, the initial collision is head-on, but the final angle of the collision undetermined from the energy and momentum. It would be determined by the impact parameter in the original frame. Therefore, we can randomly rotate the final velocities in CoM as long as they are remain oppositely directed.

Comment: So for a 2D simulation would I just use the rotation matrix $R = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\phi       & -sin\phi \\
    sin\phi & cos\phi \\
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but you won't get a true Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution. And if you are coding for 2D why not go ahead an make it 3D?

Comment: Ah that's a good point. Just thought I would get it working for 2D then it shouldn't be too hard to convert to 3D.